# Separate projects for desktop/tablets and WP8?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, tablet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the compatibility between a WinRT class library and Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501457/what-is-the-compatibility-between-a-winrt-class-library-and-windows-phone-8)

I'm designing a windows store app for desktop/tablets and WP8. The app interface will be the same for desktop/tablets, but different for WP8. Would you suggest I separate this into two projects or do everything in a single windows store app project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to separate. A Windows store app don't work on windows phone 8. You can share parts of code between win8 & wp8 using portable class libraries and winrt components, but need to do a project for windows store app and other for windows phone app.

Comment: +1. Additionally, you can't share XAML files between Win8 and WP8 projects due to XAML format inconsistencies.